# Will Github count contributions from branches merged by -no-ff merge (not fast forward)?

Tags: git, github, git-merge, fast-forward

Github article about [problems with contributions](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/) has no words about `--no-ff` merges.

I've found some answers [in this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/4vgq4d/when_youve_been_using_feature_branch_all_year/d5yaf1e/), but process is still not clear for me.

**EDIT:** E.g. i have done some commits in feature branch, then i've merged this branch with master branch. Will Github count all commits from feature branch in my profile or only a merge commit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First think about what the inverse of `--no-ff` means: That you are doing a fast-forward merge.

Now what is a fast-forward merge? Essentially this means that you are just advancing the branch pointer without actually creating any commits. Since commits are the thing that record contributions (since they hold the author/committer information), fast-forwarding will obviously not result in a visible commit contribution to a repository.

The common repository hosting solutions do track pushes to the repository, so your updated push to a branch *could* be recorded as a contribution, but this is usually not done because it’s not recordable in the repository itself.

So, when looking at non fast-forward merges, this is where you actually create a merge commit that combines two (or more) diverging branches. A merge commit, being just a normal commit, will record the committer and author information properly, so this could count as a contribution.

So now let’s check what GitHub writes about what counts as contributions:

> Commits will appear on your contributions graph if they meet **all** of the following conditions:
>
> 1. The email address used for the commits is associated with your GitHub account.
> 2. The commits were made in a standalone repository, not a fork.
> 3. The commits were made:
>
>    - In the repository's default branch (usually `master`)
>    - In the `gh-pages` branch (for repositories with [Project Pages sites](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/#project-pages))

Condition 1 is handled by your local Git configuration and how you set up your GitHub account. 2 is self-explanatory and 3 essentially requires that the merge commit lands in the default branch. If you are merging with master, this would work.

> In addition, at least one of the following must be true:
>
> 1. You are a collaborator on the repository or are a member of the organization that owns the repository.
> 2. You have forked the repository.
> 3. You have opened a pull request or issue in the repository.
> 4. You have starred the repository.

One of these should also be guaranteed if you have some sort of push access to the repository (either directly, or as part of a pull request).

So yes, a merge commit should count as a contribution.

Comment: What about other commits? 
E.g. i have done some commits in `feature` branch, then i've merged this branch with `master` branch. Will Github count all commits from `feature` branch in my profile or only a merge commit?

Comment: Maybe i should include this example in the question to make it more clear?

Comment: Since branches do not *belong to branches*, by merging the feature branch into your master branch, you are essentially publishing all the commits that previously did not exist on the master branch to it. So yeah, that should make them count too. Otherwise, there would be zero contributions on repositories that only work with pull requests.

Comment: Sounds very reasonable, but i think that it will work only with fast-forward merging since `--no-ff` merge is not adding commits to target branch...
However, commits from pull-requests is really counting

Comment: You seem to misunderstand how branches work in Git. As I said, commits do not belong to branches. It’s just branches that point to some commit in the history. And the primary action a merge does is move that pointer forward, making more commits “part” of the branch.

Comment: So, `-no-ff` flag will just force creating merge commit and other behavior will be the same?

Comment: Yes, `--no-ff` literally means “create a merge commit even if you could fast-forward the branch”, and `--ff-only` means “try to fast-forward or abort”, while not specifying anything means “try to fast-forward, or create a merge commit if you cannot fast-forward”.

Comment: Thank you for such detailed response! Everything is clear now